# Perl sending emails with attachment using net::smtp

Tags: perl, email, smtp, attachment

I have a problem! I am sending Mails with net smtp but I can not send attachments. I need to send attachments! 
I have these two lines but it does not work.

```
$NET_SMTP_MODUL->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $MAILPARAM_ATTACHMENT ."\n");
$NET_SMTP_MODUL->datasend("Content-Type: application/text; name=Attachment.txt");
```

Comment: see [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=675595)

Comment: From Jens' link: _"Net::SMTP is too lowlevel, printing all the headers and section separators and encoding the data properly etc. etc. etc. is a lot of work. Use [Mail::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Mail-Sender/Sender.pm) or [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm)."_

Comment: But [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) says: _"MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."_

Answer (score 2):

Using Net::SMTP makes your life far harder than it needs to be. Who has time to hand-craft SMTP transactions?

I would recommend taking a look at [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) instead.

Comment: If you're using ActivePerl for Windows, I don't recommend the Email::Stuffer that ActivePerl provides (version 0.009).  It's very buggy when it comes to attachments.  Grab a more recent version from CPAN, or directly from their GitHub page (https://github.com/rjbs/Email-Stuffer).

Comment: Or switch to using Strawberry Perl instead - so you can easily install the latest version of modules using the standard CPAN tools.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following url to send email with attachment

- ["How do I send an email with Perl (including an attachment)?"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=19430): Hints on using [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) (*deprecated*) or [Mail::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/~capoeirab/Mail-Sender-0.903/lib/Mail/Sender.pm) (*deprecated*) or [Mail::Send](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.20/lib/Mail/Send.pod) and handcrafting or [Mail::Sendmail](http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Test-Smoke-1.72/lib/inc/Mail/Sendmail.pm) and [MIME::QuotedPrint](https://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/QuotedPrint.html) (core module) and [MIME::Base64](https://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html) (core module) from 2000.
- ["Send mail with attachment using only SMTP"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=689054): Hints on using [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-3.11/lib/Net/SMTP.pm) from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

So... what do?

- [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-3.11/lib/Net/SMTP.pm), [Mail::Sendmail](http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Test-Smoke-1.72/lib/inc/Mail/Sendmail.pm), [Mail::Send](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.20/lib/Mail/Send.pod): Only if you want to do the attachment processing yourself. Which can be tricky. Use [MIME::QuotedPrint](https://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/QuotedPrint.html) (core module) and [MIME::Base64](https://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html) (core module) as needed.
- [Mail::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/~capoeirab/Mail-Sender-0.903/lib/Mail/Sender.pm), [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm): Deprecated!
- [Email::Stuffer](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Stuffer-0.014/lib/Email/Stuffer.pm): Sounds good.
- [Email::MIME](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-MIME-1.946/lib/Email/MIME.pm) and [IO::All](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/IO-All-0.87/lib/IO/All.pod) and [Email::Sender::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Sender-1.300031/lib/Email/Sender/Simple.pm): See below!

Here is an example using `Email::MIME`, `IO::All` and `Email::Sender::Simple`.

```
use Email::MIME; # yum install perl-Email-MIME
use IO::All; # yum install perl-IO-All
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail); # yum install perl-Email-Sender;
use Sys::Hostname;

my $hostname = hostname;
my $pwuid    = getpwuid( $< );
my $to       = 'someone@example.com';
my $cc       = join(',', ('foo@example.com','bar@example.com'));
my $from     = "$pwuid\@$hostname";

# We have a text part and an CSV part
# Send a file identified by `$filename` (a temporary file, actually) that
# should appear to be named `$finalFilename`.

my @parts;

push @parts, Email::MIME->create(
   attributes => {
      filename     => $finalFilename,
      content_type => 'text/csv',
      disposition  => 'attachment',
      encoding     => 'base64',
      name         => $finalFilename
   },
   body => io($filename)->all
);

# Create an inline text part

my $txtmsg = <<"TXTMSG";
File automatically generated on machine '$hostname' by user '$pwuid'.
TXTMSG

push @parts, Email::MIME->create(
   attributes => {
      content_type => 'text/plain',
      disposition  => 'inline',
      encoding     => 'quoted-printable',
      charset      => 'UTF-8',
   },
   body_str => $txtmsg
);

# Pack it into an email

my $email = Email::MIME->create(
   header_str => [ To      => $to,
                   Cc      => $cc,
                   From    => $from,
                   Subject => $finalFilename ],
   parts => [ @parts ]
);

# Debugging; this should be controlled by a "verbose" flag

print STDERR $email->as_string;

# Send to the local MTA which will forward, hopefully.
# This is the sendmail() of Email::Sender::Simple

my $response = sendmail($email);

# Tell the user

if (!$response) {
   print STDERR "An error occurred, got $response as response from 'sendmail: $Mail::Sendmail::error'\n";
   print STDERR $Mail::Sendmail::log;
   exit 1
}
else {
   print STDERR "Mail given to MTA!\n";
   exit 0
}
```